# Your job matches are on hold - missing explanation

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, user-experience

## Summary

Feature request: Show more information/hints on the *Developer Story* page to achieve the goal *not on hold*.

## What I do

- I am on the job search page
- I see in the job search this hint:

[image]

- I click on *Complete my Developer Story*
- I am now on the tab *Developer Story*

## What I see

- I see no hint of what I need to complete to not be on hold

## What I expect

- A detailed explanation what more information is needed to not be on hold
- A sign or a marker on the parts where more information is needed